# Currently, in VS Code, my Azure resources only show the Functions App and nothing else (Ex of what else it should show are Cosmos DB, VM)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-storage, vscode-extensions, azure-container-instances

My Azure resources only show Functions App and nothing else. I can't see Storage Accounts, Cosmos DB, or anything else but Functions. I have tried signing out, restarting, and signing back in but I'm not able to resolve it and get the rest of the resources to show. I have 2 Storage Accounts and 1 Cosmos DB account but I cannot get them to show.  I have all of the Azure extensions installed in VS Code such as Azure Account, Azure Storage, Azure Databases and many more.

Here is what I can see:
[My VS Code Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7JUa.png)

Here is what I should be able to see: [Azure with all resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhpuj.png)
or I think it should also look like this which I saw in a youtube video: [Azure with all resources 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48bXf.png)

Any help would be appreciated since I'm not sure what else to do.
Also, I'm not certain but I think this issue is causing me to have uploading issues anytime I try uploading my website files to Azure Storage because I get the following error:
“Could not find $web blob container for storage account "(name of my account)" ; When I checked in Azure my storage account, it had under "Container": $web.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Visual Studio Code of version 1.67](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67) and click on the **resources** in VS Code menu then sign in with your azure credentials.

*Recheck the below mentioned point:*

After sign in into VSCode, select the appropriate `Subscription` under **resources** in which you have all the resources like `Storage Accounts`, `Cosmos DB` and other `resources`...

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the suggestion. I installed version 1.67 with your link and then logged into Azure. I still only see the Azure Functions App only and nothing else like in my picture. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I was able to fix all of the Resources showing in the list. Next to the + sign it says "Group By" and then I selected Group By Resource Type.

Comment: **@AK_Cloud80** - Glad that you have resolved the issue and we updated the answer with the same. It may help to other community members who are experiencing the same issue.